# How to check arguments that are sent in silent mode?

Tags: inno-setup

During installation i except to get a PATH argument in the following syntax:

```
myapp.exe /SILENT /LICENSE=hostname,port
```

LICENSE argument gets a string that's actually I have to separate it later to two strings.

If the LICENSE syntax is wrong, I'd prefer to stop installation and let the user know the reason.

My questions are: how to validate this argument (regular expressions?) and how to tell the user if it's wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean how to parse a) whole command line passed to setup or b) just /LICENSE parameter?

a) Use function **ParamStr(Index: Integer): String;** to return the Index-th command line parameter passed to Setup or Uninstall.

Also you can use **function GetCmdTail: String;** to return all command line parameters passed to Setup or Uninstall as a single string together with **function ParamCount: Integer;** which returns the number of command line parameters passed to Setup or Uninstall.

b) Regex is not supported in Inno Setup so try this simple validation:

```
function CheckLicenseHostPort(): Boolean;
var
  Correct: Boolean;
  Temp, Host, PortStr: String;
  CommaPos, Port: Integer;
begin
  Correct := False;
  Temp := ParamStr(3); // '/LICENSE=hostname,port'

  CommaPos := Pos('=', Temp);
  Temp := Copy(Temp, CommaPos + 1, 999); // 'hostname,port'

  CommaPos := Pos(',', Temp);

  if(CommaPos > 0) then
  begin    
    Host := Copy(Temp, 1, CommaPos - 1);
    PortStr := Copy(Temp, CommaPos + 1, Length(Temp) - CommaPos);

    // Here we suppose port must be number 0 - 9999
    if(Length(PortStr) > 0) then
    begin
      Port := StrToIntDef(PortStr, -123); // If there is problem with converting to integer return -123
      if(Port <> -123) then
        Correct := True;
     end;
  end;

  if(Correct) then
  begin
    // Port and Host contain correct values
  end;

  Result:= Correct;
end;
```

Comment: If the parameter is specifically of the form `/name=value` or `/name="value possibly with spaces"` then you can alternatively use a `{param:name}` constant to read its value.  You would still need to split apart the hostname and port in your case unless you specified those as two separate parameters.

Comment: I meant (b) but (a) is interesting as well... Thank you

Comment: This check can be done in the `InitialiseSetup()` event function where it can report the issue and exit.